# Using ag-Grid within SharePoint Framework (SPFX) / Angular - styling failure

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid, sharepoint-online, spfx

We're exploring custom SharePoint Web Parts using SharePoint Framework (SPFX) with Angular Elements. I'd like to use ag-Grid but the style definitions of the grid contents don't seem to get applied. Following the intro [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/), the HTML looks like this:

```
  <div class="ag-theme-material">
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
>
</ag-grid-angular></div>
```

But the rendered page content looks like this:

[image: This is what the page looks like]

I've tried several of the bundled themes, and they all fail the same way.

Has anyone tried using ag-Grid with Angular Elements and SharePoint Framework? Any suggestions on how to get the styling to work?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have documentation but you don't use class in the correct way.

The class should be added for `ag-grid` but not for extra div

[image]

in your case it should be:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
  class="ag-theme-material"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

One more one of the important things is definitions of styles in root styles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @shutsman for following up. Unfortunately, putting the class property inside (as the docs describe) was how I started. I tried moving class to an enclosing div tag (described in another article) trying to find a fix. I had also added the ag-grid .css imports to the src/styles.css.

Are there any other ideas that come to mind I might try?

Comment: Did you follow this guide https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/#add-ag-grid-to-your-project ?

Comment: Yes, at first. Because this is an Angular Elements project (not a regular whole-application Angular project) only the style defs in the [component].scss file (and not those in src/styles.css) come across into the SPFX project. So I had to move the ag-grid style import statements (with updated path) into the [component].scss file to get them into the SPFX project. Unfortunately it looks like resolving that still doesn't get the ag-grid style defs applied to the ag-grid elements. They still look like the screen capture above.

Comment: After digging into the dynamically rendered page content, it looks like content that should be shifted to the right has style properties that should shift it, but the content winds up all the way at the left. For example, "Celica" has element.style / left: 200px, and "35000" has ... left: 400px but they're both at the left. So this might be more of a problem with SharePoint's limitations or negative impacts on rendering of an element's preferred styling. Ugh!

Comment: @YonatanNir I can take a look on Monday, looks like I had similar case in my project